# Is it correct to refer to a jQuery selector like this?

Tags: jquery, reference

Guys i'm wondering something from few days and i can't find the answer.

Lets say i have

```
var myJqueryObject = jQuery("span")
```

Is it correct to write the code like this. Lets say i want' to apply many other things to that span and instead of doing 
 `jQuery("span").someJqueryMethodHere();` each time.

I want to refer to the myJqueryObject and do it like this

```
myJqueryObject.css('background','#fff');
myJqueryObject.find("input);
```

Is it correct to use this approach and if is not correct Why? I think that in this way I just refer to the jquery Selector and I don't force jquery to check each time in the DOM for this "span".

I know that i can chain the methods but i'm trying to use chaining as less as i can. :). And the chaining doesn't work well with nested elements i think.

Am i correct or i'm wrong about that ?

Thank you!

Comment: Easily testable - have you tried it?

Comment: Yup, nothing wrong with that.  In fact, it is encouraged as it is slightly more efficient.

Comment: Lol that was quick :). Thank you for the answer :)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I would do it like this:

```
 var myJqueryObject = jQuery("span");
 myJqueryObject.addClass("someClass");
 myJqueryObject.css('background','#fff');
 myJqueryObject.find("input);
```

If you only want to filter certain `class`, then do this:

```
 var myJqueryObject = jQuery("span.someClass");
 myJqueryObject.css('background','#fff');
 myJqueryObject.find("input);
```

Comment: There's no reason you couldn't do your first part.

Comment: What's wrong with the first line?  Why "don't" you do that?

Comment: @DanielCook agreed, and there is a typo on the last line

Comment: Okay thats my Answer. I know that doing it like this var myJqueryObject = jQuery("span").addClass("someClass"); is not well i want the parent so i can just apply other stuffs to it and the element nested within :). Aham I wrote it wrong in my question :)

Comment: @RocketHazmat You are correct... it's just not as clean... modifying answer

Comment: @SimchaKhabinsky the "jQueriest"'s way would be to chain methods

Comment: define `clean to look at`... that's pretty subjective